# string concatenation using javascript's shorthand for pural or singular term

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.msg = 'Ok, you ate ' + num + ' hotdog' 
      + (num.length > 1) ? 's' : '' + ', got it!';
```

Why above $scope.msg return only 's' ? I expect hotdogs for pural and hotdog for singular with shorthand. Hmm couldn't catch the mistake.

Comment: why length property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the parenthesis a bit different, only for the ternary statement and take the `num` value without some property.

```
$scope.msg = 'Ok, you ate ' + num + ' hotdog' + (num > 1 ? 's' : '') + ', got it!';
```

```js
var num = 1;
console.log('Ok, you ate ' + num + ' hotdog' + (num > 1 ? 's' : '') + ', got it!');
num = 3;
console.log('Ok, you ate ' + num + ' hotdog' + (num > 1 ? 's' : '') + ', got it!');
```

If you have more than one word for pluralisation, you could use an object and a function for easier access, like

```js
function getPlural(number, word) {
    return number === 1 && word.one || word.other;
}

var hotdog = { one: 'hotdog', other: 'hotdogs' },
    num = 1;

console.log('Ok, you ate ' + num + ' ' + getPlural(num, hotdog) + ', got it!');
num = 5;
console.log('Ok, you ate ' + num + ' ' + getPlural(num, hotdog) + ', got it!');
```

Comment: I prefer 1 line code using shorthand, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You need more parentheses.

Your code is parsed as `('Ok, you ate ' + num + ' hotdog' + (num.length > 1))` ? `'s'` : `('' + ', got it!')`.

You need to wrap the entire conditional expression in parentheses.